# Error magento 2.3.3-p1 with Smile ElasticsuiteCore

Tags: magento2, upgrade

During magento upgrade to 2.3.5-p1, after doing a **composer install** this happened when I tried to do any command i.e:

**magento setup:upgrade**

The error on terminal:

```
Class Smile\ElasticsuiteCore\Model\Search\Request\RelevanceConfig\Resolver\Containers does not exist#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('Smile\\Elasticsu...')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(49): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Smile\\Elasticsu...')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(48): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Smile\\Elasticsu...')
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Smile\\Elasticsu...')
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(196): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Smile\\Elasticsu...')
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(172): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->parseArray(Array)
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, NULL, Array, 'scopeResolvers', 'Magento\\Framewo...')
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'scopeResolverPo...', 'Magento\\Framewo...')
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'scopeCodeResolv...', 'Magento\\Framewo...')
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'scopeConfig', 'Magento\\Develop...')
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Develop...', Array, Array)
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Develop...', Array, Array)
#24 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Develop...')
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(196): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Develop...')
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(172): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->parseArray(Array)
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, NULL, Array, 'handlers', 'SummaSolutions\\...')
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('SummaSolutions\\...', Array, Array)
#29 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('SummaSolutions\\...', Array, Array)
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('SummaSolutions\\...')
#31 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('SummaSolutions\\...')
#32 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Psr\\Log\\LoggerI...', NULL, 'logger', 'Magento\\Framewo...')
#33 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)
#34 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)
#35 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#36 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#37 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'logger', 'Magento\\Framewo...')
#38 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)
#39 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)
#40 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#41 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(197): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#42 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(161): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Factory->_applyDecorators(Object(Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\TagScope))
#43 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Pool.php(67): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Factory->create(Array)
#44 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Pool.php(146): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool->_initialize()
#45 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache.php(38): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool->get('default')
#46 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\Cache->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool))
#47 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#48 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#49 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Proxy.php(44): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#50 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Proxy.php(67): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Proxy->_getCache()
#51 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ProductMetadata.php(80): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Proxy->load('mage-version')
#52 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(92): Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata->getVersion()
#53 /var/www/html/bin/magento(22): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct('Magento CLI')
#54 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution over here:

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034633551

The solution was to flush redis cache.